# JMSSerializer — Exclude Properties by condition

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have created an Symfony3 Entity like so (shortened):

```
class Group
{
  /**
   * …
   */
  private name;

  /**
   * …
   *@JMS\Exclude()
   */
  private $styles;
}
```

On the route `[GET] list/groups`, this is fine, since it should generate a list containing where each Item should only contain the id and name.

But on the route `[GET] group/{id}`, I would like to deliver more details to the client, including styles and more.

How can I exclude/include properties of the entity by condition/route?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the answer of @Genoud Magloire I could manage to do it like so:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Context\Context;

$view = $this->view($group);
$context = new Context();
$context->addGroup('detail');
$view->setContext($context);

return $this->handleView($view);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@Group` annotation as explain [Here](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#creating-different-views-of-your-objects) to create different views of your object.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach available in the version v1.5 are the exclusions by expression language.

Visiting https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/pull/673 you can see how to exclude a property using any service call.

Basically is:

```
class Person
{
    /**
     * @Expose(if="service('some.cool.service').isAllowed(object)")
     */
    public $gender;
    /**
     * @Exclude(if="service('some.cool.service').isAllowed(object)")
     */
    public $gender;
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example without services? I couldn't find any example for this feature expect for expressions like "true" or some dummy methods.

Comment: Inside the "if" you can put any of the expressions shown on https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html

Comment: thanks. I already read this article. My question is in the combination by JMS Serializer. For example how can I check the current depth in the expression (accessing the context); or how can I check the other properties(accessing the current object). In the [documentation](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#dynamic-exclusion-strategy) is this example: `@Exclude(if="someMethod(object, context, property_metadata)")`. But there is no information how/where can we define this function.

Comment: Also as i tried it is not possible to use object, context, and property_metadata directly in the expression.

Comment: are you using it via symfony bundle ? if not, you have to implement by your self something as https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/blob/master/ExpressionLanguage/BasicSerializerFunctionsProvider.php

Comment: have you tried `service('some_service').someMethod(object, context, property_metadata)` ? obviously you have to define somewhere `some_service`

Comment: If the only way to use a function in expression annotation is through services then definitely the documentation is misleading/incomplete. My first question was to use a function without services since the documentation doesn't mention anything about services but still it mentions about using a function in expression.

Comment: i understand your disappointment, but this is how the symfony expression language works. you can always register your custom functions (see symfony docs to see how to do it), but is not available out of the box

Comment: after all those comments I still don't get how to use someMethod function with Expression Language.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/extending.html is a guide on how to add custom functions to the symfony expression language